# Business Intelligence Installation QUESTIONS. Another 2008 vs 2005 thing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, bids

Alright I know there is a lot on here about this, but I haven't gotten the information nor the answer.

I have Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2005. (I want to keep using 2008)

I have Microsoft SQL Server 2005. (Without BIDS)

Which version of BIDS should I get. If I get BIDS 2008 will it work even though I use SQL 2005.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to have VS2005 and VS2008 Running side by side aka both installed on the computer along with BIDS for each. Luckily, hard drives are huge these days.

i found this link that actually had the answer which was:

I think what I was bascially asking is that, If I install visual studio 2008, and lets say I already had visual 2005 installed, then to create a business intellijance project I must install interation service for 2008.  Integration service from 2005 is not going to work on visual studio 2008 is what it seems like.

That's correct. To create SSIS packages for SQL Server 2008 you will need to use Visual Studio 2008 with the SSIS project template that is installed when you install the SSIS components. You cannot use Visual Studio 2005 to create SSIS 2008 packages, nor can you use Visual Studio 2008 to create SSIS 2005 packages.

[msdn](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/d97291b9-f7f4-4b75-a1d0-55d49ea3be3b/)

Answer (score 4):

BIDS 2008 can connect to databases of earlier versions. The question is where are you going to run the packages from if you don't have at least one 2008 server? I've not tried to schedule a 2008 package on a 2005 server, but I suspect it can't be done.